# Conditionally change Repeater DropDownList background color?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

We are trying to change the background color of Repeater DropDownList to Gray when RadioButtonList selectedItem is New.

Otherwise, keep the background as White.

The following code keeps the background to Gray whether RadioButtonList selectedItem is New or Used.

What am I missing?

//css

```
<style>
    .disabledcss
    {
        background-color: #F9F9F9;
        color: blue;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        color: Gray;
    }
</style>
<style>
    .enabledcss
    {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: blue;
        border: 1px solid white;
        color: Gray;
    }
</style>
```

//markup:

```
<tr>
<td>
Item Type:<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblPType" runat="server" ValidationGroup ="stype" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" TextAlign="Right" style="display:inline;"  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblPurchaseType_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Text="New" />
<asp:ListItem Text="Used" />
</asp:RadioButtonList><br />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator style="color:#ff0000;" id="RequiredFieldValidator1"  ControlToValidate="rblPurchaseType" ErrorMessage="Please choose New or Used"  ValidationGroup ="stype" runat="server" />
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<asp:Panel ID="uPanel" runat="server" Enabled="false">
STATE: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" cssClass="disabledcss enabledcss" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
  <asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>    
 </div></span></asp:Panel>
</td>
</tr>
```

C# in ItemDataBound event

```
RadioButtonList rbPurchase = e.Item.FindControl("rblPType") as RadioButtonList;

foreach (RepeaterItem ReapterItem in Repeater2.Items)
{
    var rblType = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlState");
    if (rblType.Enabled == false)
    {
        rblType.CssClass = "disabledcss";
    }
    else
    {
        rblType.CssClass = "enabledcss";
    }
}
```

Note: I have seen about three examples on this forum that do not apply to myself.
Thank you

Comment: on your browser html, Does your class is coming ?

Comment: Why do you use both cssClass="disabledcss enabledcss"? Also could you send the complete HTML markup?

Comment: @SamanGholami, I initially used the disabledcss class which resulted to just Gray background. Adding the enabledcss class did not make any difference. I posted it here anyway just in case I may have left something out.

Complete css is 1500 lines long. I posted the relevant code.

Comment: Post the code of the ASP controls, not CSS

Comment: I did.  I posted the asp controls (RadioButtonList and DropDownList) controls.

Both are inside a Repeater. I also posted the C# I am using in ItemDataBound event.

Answer (score 0):

You're using both css classes to style the drop downlist.

```
cssClass="disabledcss enabledcss"
```

You need to clarify the use of one or the other - this can be used with JQuery - adding and removing classes from the dropdownlist. Or try something like this:

```
if (rblType.Enabled == false)
{
    // rblType.CssClass = "disabledcss";
    rblType.CssClass = rblType.CssClass.Replace("enabledcss", "disabledcss");
}
else
{
    // rblType.CssClass = "enabledcss";
    rblType.CssClass = rblType.CssClass.Replace("disabledcss", "enabledcss");
}
```

Just have one css class in your dropdownlist.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" cssClass="disabledcss" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
```

Comment: Yes, I totally agree that this could have been done in JQuery. That's my preference too but Repeater control is too picky when it comes to RadioButtonList and DropDownList.

Thanks for your help.
As effected, it is causing an error.

Comment: Yes, the only change was removing enabledcss per your directive.

That's why I didn't go JQuery route. 

For some reason, maybe due to my little knowledge with Repeater, JQuery has difficulty reading Repeater controls which is where the RadioButtonList and DropDownList controls.